# Direct Line App Extension - How and where are messages cached?

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-bot-service, direct-line-botframework

I have a few questions about the new [Direct Line App Extension for App Services on Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-directline-extension?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) announced at Build 2020.
The "normal" direct line services cached messages at their own regional servers. Now that this extension allows the App Service of a bot to act as the Direct Line endpoint, is the conversation with it's messages cached in the app service? And does this mean, one could for example edit the settings of the conversation caching like cache duration etc.?

And I guess the pricing of messages via the Direct Line App Extension is still via the premium channel pricing category?

I tried to find information about it in the botframework repositories and in the documentation, but it seems like there is no additional information about it available **yet**.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Direct Line Application Service Extension does not cache messages at all. This is by design as caching would require access to your app service storage, which means you would need storage, or access to an outside service. However, adding a caching service defeats the purpose of the VNET scenario DL ASE was primarily built to serve.

Regarding pricing, the Bot Service tiers are the same in both a Direct Line bot and one that utilizes DL ASE. So, on the face of it, they appear the same.

Comment: For pricing, I've reached out to a contact to verify this. If I hear otherwise (i.e. pricing is / will be different or there are additional costs), I'll update my answer.

Comment: Also see: https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Services/issues/219