# How to reconnect to conversation using DirectLine App Service Extension?

Tags: c#, botframework, direct-line-botframework

I am using the DirectLine 3.0.3-preview NuGet package to create a .NET client using DirectLine App Service Extension. I am able to establish a connection and start a new conversation via WebSockets using `directLineClient.StreamingConversations.ConnectAsync(conversationId, receiveMessageCallback)`

I am saving the conversationId generated from that session. However when I try to use that conversationId to create a new connection, I am not able to reconnect:

```
// Initialize a DirectLineClient using the secret.
var directLineClient = new DirectLineClient(
                           new Uri(_directLineEndpoint),
                           new DirectLineClientCredentials(_directLineSecret));

var conversation =  await directLineClient.Conversations
                             .ReconnectToConversationAsync(savedConversationId);
```

When I execute the code above, I get a null conversation object. This does not happen when I do the same approach before I moved to using App Service Extensions.

Is there a new way to reconnect to an existing conversation via WebSockets using DirectLine App Service Extension?

Answer (score 0):

So after researching further, it seems that DirectLine App Service Extension does not support message caching, as mentioned by answers and comments from this thread:

[Direct Line App Extension - How and where are messages cached?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62131380/direct-line-app-extension-how-and-where-are-messages-cached)