# Persist chat history with Bot Framework using DirectLine ASE

Tags: javascript, botframework, chatbot, direct-line-botframework

we are integrating our chatbot into our website. We got most of it working using Direct Line App Service Extension. I used this sample to implement our bot:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-directline-extension-webchat-client?view=azure-bot-service-4.0

Part of our code looks like this:

```
var token = sessionStorage['webchatToken'];
var userId = sessionStorage['webchatUserId'];
var conversationId = sessionStorage['webchatConversationId'];

directLine = await window.WebChat.createDirectLineAppServiceExtension({
  token,
  domain: 'https://ourbot.azurewebsites.net/.bot/v3/directline',
  watermark: "0"
});

window.WebChat.renderWebChat(
  { directLine: directLine },
  document.getElementById('webchat')
);
document.querySelector('#webchat > *').focus();
```

Now I'm trying to make it so that the bot persists chat history when the user navigates our website.
I already store the token, conversationId and userId in sessionStorage.

Basically what I need is some way to pass the `conversationId` to the `createDirectLineAppServiceExtension` function. Or maybe some other way to set `directLine` that fills it with the chat history based on the `conversationId`.

Any help is appreciated. I would like to mention that `Direct Line` and `Direct Line App Service Extension` are 2 different things. Thanks in advance!

PS: I can't find any documentation for the `createDirectLineAppServiceExtension` method other than the above mentioned link. So if you have documentation for this, I would a link. Most documentation I can find is not about the app service extension.

======= EDIT ======

I decided to use regular DirectLine instead of DirectLine ASE. And I got everything working perfectly. Maybe an answer to this question can still be useful to others. Though I would advise them to do as I did and got with regular DirectLine as it works and is better documented.

Comment: There is also this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-directline-extension?view=azure-bot-service-4.0

And it seems like we are trying to solve the same problem but me with the traditional directline : https://stackoverflow.com/q/63782062/1250030

Comment: Thanks for the link. To me it seems our problems are different in that your token is expired and my token is still active.

Comment: Yes, this would be a difference. Maybe you can add a `conversationId: conversationId` property to `createDirectLineAppServiceExtension`? `createDirectLine` takes one. Just a guess.

Comment: That does not seem to do anything. Nice suggestion though.

Comment: Too bad. And for me this doesn't work because the token has the wrong convId. We need Microsoft to step in here.

Comment: Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63716073/how-to-reconnect-to-conversation-using-directline-app-service-extension & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62131380/direct-line-app-extension-how-and-where-are-messages-cached