# How to reconnect WebChat to old conversation with an expired token

Tags: node.js, botframework, web-chat

I want to reconnect to an old bot conversation in WebChat if my token has expired, which could happen if network connection was lost or whatever.

I am using WebChat essentially like so:

```
directline = window.WebChat.createDirectLine({ token: token });

window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
   directLine: directline
}, document.getElementById('webchat'));
```

The token I generate with

```
cres = await fetch('https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/tokens/generate', {
   body: JSON.stringify({ User: { Id: userID }, TrustedOrigins: [origin] }),
   headers: {
      authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.DIRECT_LINE_SECRET}`,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
   },
   method: 'POST'
});
```

According to https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/docs/API.md

`createDirectLine` takes a `conversationId` parameter so I tried to pass the old conversation id

```
directline = window.WebChat.createDirectLine({ token: token, conversationId: oldConvId });
```

with a newly generated token for the same userID. But then `renderWebChat` fails with invalid token because the new token also got a new `conversationId`, which doesn't match the one requested in the directLine call. How can I solve this problem? Either do the reconnect completely differently or generate a new token for a given `userId` and `conversationId`. I couldn't find anything in the `v3/directline/token/generate` API to request a token for a given conversationId.

Answer (score 4):

Tokens are closely tied to the conversationId's they are generated with. Unfortunately, once a token expires (after 1800 seconds / 30 mins) there is no option to refresh it to then reconnect to the conversation the original token represented.

If you want a user to be able to re-join a conversation, then the token should be refreshed before they expire by calling the [refresh API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-api-reference?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#refresh-token) `/directline/tokens/refresh` to obtain a new one. Then you must persist the token and conversationId for use in [reconnecting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-reconnect-to-conversation?view=azure-bot-service-4.0). This can be done via localStorage/sessionStorage or cookies.

In this scenario, you will setup a token server to make the Direct Line API calls when your own server endpoints are contacted. Once you have the refresh API setup on your token server, you Web Chat instance will call your refresh endpoint for a new token. This can be done every 25 mins before the current token expires. The new token should then be persisted.

Bear in mind, `localStorage` is only good for page refreshes and navigating away from and back to Web Chat. If the browser is closed, the session will be lost. `sessionStorage` will persist across closed browser sessions, but if the period of inactivity is longer than 30 mins, the token will expire as Web Chat isn't open to refresh the token. (The same can be said about localStorage if the user navigates away for longer than 30 mins.)

If the token *is* expired, another option is to retrieve the [conversation history](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-api-reference?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#send-conversation-history) by use of the expired `token` and the associated `conversationId`. You could repopulate Web Chat's transcript with the previous conversation and continue it with a new conversation that, from the user's perspective, looks to be the same. This wouldn't be the easiest method and would require some additional logic to get right, but it is theoretically doable.

One last consideration, in particular to the above, is the conversationId is only stored and accessible for 14 days and the conversation for 24 hours. If you need to access either of these for a longer period, then you will need a storage solution to store them in (Cosmos DB, SQL, Mongo, etc.).

Hope of help!

Comment: Great answer. You need to swith local and sessionstorage however. localStorage persists closed browser sessions. sessionstorage does not.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried to get the history but couldn't get it to work with an expired token (via GET /v3/directline/conversations/${conversationid}) With the expired token I get a 401 response, using the directline secret I get asked to provide a user id, and using the WebChat secret the conversation is never found. Then I found this: https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-DirectLineJS/issues/191#issuecomment-529630099 So it seems I am out of luck? So how to get at the chat history without doing something big like this: https://github.com/EricDahlvang/BotFramework-WebChat/pull/1